# Github pages - how to reuse html code on each page (like a nav bar)

Tags: html, github-pages

I found many answers to this question, but it was often outdated or I failed to make it work.

I have a nav-bar and I want to call it on each pages so when I want to update it, I need to change only one instance of the nav bar and not multiple instances on many pages.

How can I do it please? I am using Github pages, maybe it matters somehow.

Thanks

Comment: This can be done with a framework (backend or frontend) and you cant do this with a vanilla html, css and javascript.

Comment: thx. Is there any beginner friendly framework you would recommend please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github-pages uses [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), which on its own uses [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki).

If I've understood you correctly,
You can achieve what you want by using `include` syntax in [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki) which is referenced [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers).

You can find more information about `include` in [here](https://documentation.platformos.com/api-reference/liquid/include) and [this blog post](https://blog.avada.io/shopify/devdocs/liquid-include-how-to-include-a-file-in-liquid.html).

[This project](https://github.com/rundocs/jekyll-rtd-theme/blob/develop/_layouts/default.liquid) uses different scenarios of `include`.

Github-pages is a powerful static site generator and you can achieve a lot by using it, checkout [this list](https://github.com/collections/github-pages-examples).

Comment: I can confirm this works and it was quite easy. thank you